# classic ASP regex to get all pages from local domain

Tags: regex, asp-classic

Hello i need a regex expression to get all the links from a localdomain no external websites.
Till now i have this but returning only outside pages

```
<%function getPage(strURL)
dim strBody, objXML

set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    objXML.Open "GET", strURL, False
    'objXML.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "ddd" '===  falsify the agent
    'objXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; Charset:ISO-8859-1"
    'objXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; Charset:UTF-8"
    objXML.Send  
    status = objXML.status 
if err.number <> 0 or status <> 200 then 
    if status = 404 then 
        Response.Write "[EFERROR]Page does not exist (404)." 
    elseif status >= 401 and status < 402 then 
        Response.Write "[EFERROR]Access denied (401)." 
    elseif status >= 500 and status <= 600 then 
        Response.Write "[EFERROR]500 Internal Server Error on remote site." 
    else 
        Response.write "[EFERROR]Server is down or does not exist." 
    end if 
      end if
    strBody = objXML.responseText

set objXML = nothing
getPage = strBody
'First, create a reg exp object
Dim objRegExp
Set objRegExp = New RegExp

objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = "<a\s+href=""http://(.*?)"">\s*((\n|.)+?)\s*</a>"

'Display all of the matches
Dim objMatch
For Each objMatch in objRegExp.Execute(strBody)
  Response.Write("http://" & objMatch.SubMatches(0) & "<br>")
Next

end function


getPage("http://www.google.com")
%>
```

thank you

Comment: i try to do a kind of spider to get all internal links from homepage and show me o the screen

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps stating the obvious, but if your searching for links in "localdomain.com" isn't this just

```
objRegExp.Pattern = "<a\s+href=""http://(.*?)localdomain\.com"">\s*((\n|.)+?)\s*</a>"
```

?

**edit**: 
    the regex pattern could perhaps use the passed in url in this way:

```
objRegExp.Pattern = "<a\s+href=""" & strURL & "(.*?)"">\s*((\n|.)+?)\s*</a>"
```

retrieved matches would need to append that strURL too:

```
For Each objMatch in objRegExp.Execute(strBody)
  Response.Write("http://" & strURL &  objMatch.SubMatches(0) & "<br>")
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. I posted this because i don't know Regex... your Pattern doesn't return anything in my example.I just need a patern that return only localdomain URL's from the homepage .

Comment: Oh, sorry.. I answered to hastily... you are already passing in your url off course.. it should be using the passed in url... I'll edit my answer for that.

Comment: it doesn't do what i expected.. it should show me a list with all url's in the index page of strURL that are inside that strURL .. i mean if i see there a link to yahoo.com to ignore that .. show me only the links on strURL from the index page .. so only pages hosted on google.com